# How Do I Antialias Graphics (Circle) in PixiJS?

Tags: javascript, antialiasing, pixi.js

i've been having trouble getting a smooth circumference when i draw a circle using pixi js. I can already see a few corners when i draw big circles, and it gets so much worse when i size it down. (A small circle is what I need).

Here's the code:

```js
renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(
  document.getElementById("animations-canvas").width,
  document.getElementById("animations-canvas").height,
  {
     view:document.getElementById("animations-canvas"),
  },
  false, true
); 

var stage = new PIXI.Container();


circle = new PIXI.Graphics();
circle.beginFill(0xFFFFFF); 
circle.drawCircle(60, 60, 50); 
circle.endFill();
stage.addChild(circle);

renderer.render(stage);
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<canvas id="animations-canvas"></canvas> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.3.4/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, let me know if you need some more info about my code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 15):

Don't you just need to pass `antialias:true` to the startup params? [See the docs](http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.html#.autoDetectRenderer)

```js
renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(
  document.getElementById("animations-canvas").width,
  document.getElementById("animations-canvas").height,
  {
     view:document.getElementById("animations-canvas"),
     antialias: true,  // ADDED!!!
  },
  false, true
); 

var stage = new PIXI.Container();


circle = new PIXI.Graphics();
circle.beginFill(0xFFFFFF); 
circle.drawCircle(60, 60, 50); 
circle.endFill();
stage.addChild(circle);

renderer.render(stage);
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<canvas id="animations-canvas"></canvas> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.3.4/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

Not sure what you're `false, true` arguments are at the end of your call to `PIXI.autoDetectRenderer`

You could also pass a higher number for `resolution` though you'll need to correctly set your CSS

```js
renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(
  document.getElementById("animations-canvas").width,
  document.getElementById("animations-canvas").height,
  {
     view:document.getElementById("animations-canvas"),
     antialias: true,  // ADDED!!!
     resolution: 2,    // ADDED!!!
  },
  false, true
); 

var stage = new PIXI.Container();


circle = new PIXI.Graphics();
circle.beginFill(0xFFFFFF); 
circle.drawCircle(60, 60, 50); 
circle.endFill();
stage.addChild(circle);

renderer.render(stage);
```

```css
/* -- ADDED -- */
#animations-canvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<canvas id="animations-canvas"></canvas> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.3.4/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! the antialias:true and resolution did the trick for me, one more question, do you think that setting the resolution to a higher value would affect performance in any way? thanks again!

Comment: A higher resolution will always mean more strain on the system. If the width & height of your canvas was 1920x1080, for example, then setting your resolution to 2 will mean you will be rendering out at 4k resolution! You just have to find the right combination for the devices & browsers you support. Don't be afraid to have the resolution lower for, say, older mobile devices compared to desktop browsers!

Comment: You could also consider doing like PC game where the user can pick `Options->Graphics->Resolution` and choose settings that run ok on their system. Of course I don't know what you're making. If you were using pixi just to render a static chart from a spreadsheet then perf probably isn't an issue

Answer (score 7):

Works with v5.1.5:

```js
const app = new PIXI.Application({
  ...
  antialias: true,
  autoDensity: true, // !!!
  resolution: 2,
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Also understand that graphics, when drawn by WebGL, uses the stencil buffer, which doesn't actually allow anti-aliasing. So if you want the drawn circle to be so, then covert what you have drawn into a texture and use that within a sprite instead.

http://pixijs.download/v4.3.4/docs/PIXI.Graphics.html#generateCanvasTexture

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the antialias and the resolution did the trick for me already. cheers!

Comment: This works perfectly in my use case where I need to draw lots of tiny, identical circles. I can first create a larger texture and just reuse it over and over.

Answer (score 4):

In case you can't / won't use antialias on a renderer level, here's a little trick to antialias a specific graphic.

```js
var radius = 20; 

// Create "intermediary" container for graphics
var gContainer = new PIXI.Container();
stage.addChild(gContainer);

var myCircle = new PIXI.Graphics();
gContainer.addChild(myCircle);

// Draw graphic x2 size
myCircle.beginFill(0xFF0000);
myCircle.drawCircle(0, 0, radius * 2);

// Use cacheAsBitmap to render bitmap 
gContainer.cacheAsBitmap = true;

// Scale down (the bitmap) to get smooth edges
gContainer.scale.set(0.5);
```

If you need to update your graphic, just set cacheAsBitmap = false, do the updates, and then set cacheAsBitmap = true again.

Do keep in mind a texture is rendered for each update, which is far less efficient than just redrawing the graphic itself.